# pass sas macro variables to VB script as parameters

Tags: vba, sas

Below is the SAS code used to do forecasting and then create a excel output, once the output is stored in the excel file, i call a VBA macro to generate a graph for each excel file and for each sheet of the work book.

In SAS Macro i have defined a output path for my excel files and i want the same path to be used in VBA macro without making it a fixed value, so if i run this sas code to get a output at a different location my VBA picks up that path from sas macro variable.

```
/* SAS Code below */

%macro forcaseting(lib,dsn);

     options fmtsearch=(sasuser work);

     proc sql noprint;
           select distinct name INTO :VAR_NAME SEPARATED BY '|' 
                from dictionary.columns
                    where 
                       UPCASE(libname) = "%upcase(&LIB.)"
                       AND
                       UPCASE(MEMNAME) = "%upcase(&DSN)"
                       AND 
                       UPCASE(NAME) NE 'MONTH'
                       and
                       upcase(type) = 'NUM'
           ;
     QUIT;

    %put &var_name;

    PROC DATASETS LIB=WORK NOLIST KILL;RUN;

    PROC FORMAT;
        PICTURE MNY
            LOW - HIGH = '%b-%Y' (DATATYPE=DATE);
    RUN;

     %PUT &VAR_NAME.;
     %let i = 1;

     %do %while (%scan(&VAR_NAME.,&i,%str(|)) ne );
           %let cur_var = %scan(&VAR_NAME.,&i,%str(|));
           %put &cur_var.;

           data %sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var.,,kad));
                set &LIB..&DSN.(keep= Month &cur_var.);
                retain n 0;
                if not missing(&cur_var.) and (&cur_var. gt 0) then n +1;
                call symputx ("n",n,'l');
           run;


           %if %sysevalf(&n.) gt 5 %then %do;

           /*Forecasting using HPF*/
           proc hpf data=%sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var.,,kad)) outfor=%sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._for,,kad))
                outstat=%sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._stat,,kad))
                lead=4;
                id month interval=month;
                forecast &cur_var./ model=bestall criterion=mape;
           run;

           Data _forecast;
                length Deal_Name $ 60.;
                set %sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._for,,kad));
                Deal_Name = "&cur_var.";
                if ACTUAL not in (0 .) then mape = abs((ACTUAL-PREDICT)/ACTUAL);
                else mape=.;
                format mape percent8.2;
           run;

           Data _Final_forecast (drop=_:)  ;
           length Deal_Name $ 60.;
           set
           %if %sysfunc(exist(_final_forecast)) %then %do;
                _Final_forecast 
           %end;
/*                %sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._for,,kad));*/
                _forecast
                ;
           run;
           options nomprint nomlogic;

;

           /*Forecasting using ARIMA*/

            PROC ARIMA data=%sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var.,,kad));
                 IDENTIFY  VAR=&cur_var. ; 
                 ESTIMATE  p=1 q=1 ;/*input=per_BL_ACS */;
                 run;
                 forecast lead=4 id=month interval=month out=%sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._arima,,kad));
            run;
            quit;


        /*Get Observation count of the above dataset */
            %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(%sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._arima,,kad))));
            %let num=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid.,nlobs));
            %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));


                %if %eval(&num.) gt 1 %then %do;
                     ods tagsets.ExcelXP file="C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_ARIMA\&cur_var..xls" style=Normal 
                     options (
                                sheet_label=' ' 
                                sheet_Name="&cur_var."
                                suppress_bylines='yes' 
                                autofit_height='Yes'
                                autofilter='ALL'
                                frozen_headers='1'
                                orientation = 'Landscape'
                                );
                            data %sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._F,,kad));
                                set %sysfunc(compress(A_&cur_var._arima,,kad));
                                if &cur_var not in (. 0) then mape = abs((&cur_var-forecast)/&cur_var.);
                                else mape=.;
                                format mape percent8.2;
                            run;
                            proc print noobs;run;
                     ods tagsets.ExcelXP close;
                        ;
                 %end;
            %end;
            %let i = %eval(&i.+1);
     %end;

     ods tagsets.ExcelXP file="C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_HPF\HPF.XLS" style=Normal 
     options (
                sheet_interval='bygroup'
                sheet_label=' ' 
                suppress_bylines='yes' 
                autofit_height='Yes'
                autofilter='ALL'
                frozen_headers='1'
                orientation = 'Landscape'
                );
     proc sort data=_Final_forecast;
           by Deal_Name;
     run;

     proc print  data=_Final_forecast noobs ;
           by Deal_Name;
     run;
     ods tagsets.ExcelXP close;
;

/*Create Graph for each of the above file using two VBA CODES */
    /*Intiate Excel     */
    OPTIONS NOXWAIT NOXSYNC;
    DATA _NULL_;
        RC=SYSTEM('START EXCEL');
        RC=SLEEP(5);
    RUN;

    /*Call VBA macro to create graph for each excel file and for each sheet*/
    filename sas2xl dde 'excel|system';
    data _null_;
        file sas2xl;
        put "[open(""C:\VbaTrustedLocation\Arima_template.xlsm"", 0 , true)]";
        put "[run(""create_Arima_Chart"")]";
        put "[run(""create_Hpf_Chart"")]";
        *put '[save.as("C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_ARIMA\acosta1.xls")]';
        put '[file.close(false)]';
        put '[quit()]';
    run;
%mend forcaseting;

/* VB MACRO CODE BELOW */

Sub create_Arima_Chart()

    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim cell As Range, strTemp As String, c As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    StrFile = Dir("C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_ARIMA\*.xls") ' Looks up each file with CSV extension

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0 ' While the file name is greater then nothing
         Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_ARIMA\" & StrFile  ' Open current workbook

        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
               For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                Worksheets(i).Activate
               For Each cell In Intersect(Range("A1:H30"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
                   strTemp = cell.Value
                   For Each c In Array("XZ")
                       strTemp = strTemp & Range(c & cell.Row).Value
                   Next c
                   If Trim(strTemp) = "." Then
                       cell.ClearContents
                   End If
               Next cell


               Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth = 9.57

                ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select ' Add a chart
                ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine ' Add a chart type
                ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A1:$C1", Range("$A1:$C1").End(xlDown)) ' Set the source range to be the used cells in A:B on the open worksheet

                With ActiveChart.Parent
                    .Height = .Height * 1 'Increase Height by 50%
                    .Width = .Width * 1.2 'Increase Width by 50%
                    .Top = 20
                    .Left = 450
                End With
                With ActiveChart
                   .Legend.Select
                   Selection.Position = xlBottom
                   .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
                   Selection.Delete
                 End With

            'Note the setting of the source will only work while there are no skipped blank if you
            'have empty rows in the source data please tell me and i can provide you with another
            ' way to get the information
         Next i
    Next sh

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_ARIMA\output\" & StrFile, _
                    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False  ' Save file as excel xlsx with current files name

                ActiveWorkbook.Close ' Close when finished before opening next file this can be removed if you'd like to keep all open for review at the end of loop.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    StrFile = Dir ' Next File in Dir
Loop

End Sub


Sub create_Hpf_Chart()

    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim cell As Range, strTemp As String, c As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    StrFile = Dir("C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_HPF\*.xls") ' Looks up each file with CSV extension

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0 ' While the file name is greater then nothing
         Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_HPF\" & StrFile  ' Open current workbook

        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
               For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                Worksheets(i).Activate
               For Each cell In Intersect(Range("A1:H30"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
                   strTemp = cell.Value
                   For Each c In Array("XZ")
                       strTemp = strTemp & Range(c & cell.Row).Value
                   Next c
                   If Trim(strTemp) = "." Then
                       cell.ClearContents
                   End If
               Next cell


               Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth = 9.57

                ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select ' Add a chart
                ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine ' Add a chart type
                ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A1:$C1", Range("$A1:$C1").End(xlDown)) ' Set the source range to be the used cells in A:B on the open worksheet

                With ActiveChart.Parent
                    .Height = .Height * 1 'Increase Height by 50%
                    .Width = .Width * 1.2 'Increase Width by 50%
                    .Top = 20
                    .Left = 450
                End With
                With ActiveChart
                   .Legend.Select
                   Selection.Position = xlBottom
                   .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
                   Selection.Delete
                 End With

            'Note the setting of the source will only work while there are no skipped blank if you
            'have empty rows in the source data please tell me and i can provide you with another
            ' way to get the information
         Next i
    Next sh

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data\SASOutput\BPO\OUTPUT_PROC_ARIMA\output\" & StrFile, _
                    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False  ' Save file as excel xlsx with current files name

                ActiveWorkbook.Close ' Close when finished before opening next file this can be removed if you'd like to keep all open for review at the end of loop.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    StrFile = Dir ' Next File in Dir
Loop

End Sub




/*%forcaseting(bpo,ATTRITION_MONTHWISE_MAY_FORECAST);*/
```

Comment: pass the location as parameter

Comment: You've got way too much code there.  I strongly suggest posting a short, self-contained example that shows what you're interested in without any other detail, so we don't have to spend time wading through code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with creating a DOS script, and the solution I came up with, which may be applicable here, was to create the script with the parameters coded into the script and simply call the script itself.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a couple of changes in the approach. Rather than using a VBA macro to make the spreadsheet, I would create a standalone VBScript that accepts command line arguments. The syntax would be largely the same since VBS and VBA have significant overlap. VBS command line arguments are positional and indexed from 0, and are referenced as `WScript.Arguments(0)`, etc. Then in your SAS program, just do this after you've created the output file:

```
options xsync noxwait;

data _null_;
    shell = 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe';
    script = '"C:\Path-to-your-VBS\script.vbs"';
    args = "&macrovar";
    call system(catx(' ', shell, script, args));
run;
```

The `xsync` option tells SAS to wait for VBScript to finish before continuing with the execution of the program. The `noxwait` option tells SAS to run the command line junk without prompting you further.

If you have a 64-bit OS and 32-bit Microsoft Office (as I do), you might need to run VBS using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe` rather than the default `cscript.exe`.

I tend to avoid using DDE from SAS. I personally find this to be a cleaner approach. This also eliminates the need for a macro-enabled Excel workbook since the formatting is done outside of Excel through VBScript.